# How do I choose columns in SourceTree history hiew

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree

I somehow messed up my SourceTree history view and now cannot see any column except for description. I cannot find how to restore it.

This is Sourcetree 4.0.2 on a Mac.

I am sure that it has happened to me before but I cannot remember how I fixed it.

[image]

Comment: Right click on the column? You might find that you can select/deselect which columns are visible. At least that's what you can do in other apps.

Comment: Yes that is how a normal app would do it. There is no right clicking option here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to get it working

If you do a long press on the column you get a very volatile and awkward hand. If you just keep trying dragging to the right the missing columns sometimes appear.

It is very cumbersome and I find it amazing that this has persisted so long.

Comment: Super helpful! ..and amazingly unintuitive from Sourcetree. If you drag to the right enough times, you'll get graph, commit, author, and date added.

Comment: Thank you!! I was trying to see more of the graph by dragging the Description column to the right when the graph disappeared completely. Long-pressing the column heading and dragging right caused it to reappear in a janky way but releasing it restored it correctly.